# Programming Xilinx XC9572

Tags: programming, programmable-logic, repair

Can I read and save the program from a Xilinx XC9572 and burn it to another blank DC9572?  I have a Needhams EMP30 which has this device on its list. I need the adapter for the PLCC 44 pin to DIP. But before I buy it I need to know if it can be done.

Background:
You know that Coin-op Arcade game Hydro Thunder by Midway Games?  It is about 10 plus years old.  It is a sit down boat racing game.  It runs on a computer that uses a kind of custom 3dfx Obsidian 2 PCI video card.

Both of my games have blank screens and I get the 1 long 2 short beeps.   I have some similar video cards that are used in a different called Gauntlet Legends.  What everyone says it if you swap the Xilinx XC9572 chips the card should work.

So I put a socket on both the Hydro and the Gauntlet video cards and swapped the chips but it still doesn't work.  I confirmed that both of the cards work in the Gauntlet video game but not in the Hydro Thunder.  So that tells me that every part of the video card is  OK except for this chip.

I think this chip has the Video Options BIOS on it. Might there be some other reason why I get this 1 long 2 short error?  I have heard that this is called a secondary video card, what ever that means. But is there some special way to configure a secondary video card?  It gives me the same errors no matter what motherboard I put it in.

They want up to $450.00 for these Hydro Thunder video cards which are worth maybe 20.00 for any version except the Hydro Thunder.  It is either this chip is bad or it needs some kind of configuration.  I don't understand why just this chip would go bad on both of them. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that making a copy of the contents of that chip means you are making a copy of content that might very well be under copyright protection. If you're doing it for yourself, and own both copies, it might perhaps be fair use. If you actually care about whether it's legal or not, then I suggest consulting someone licensed to interpret the law in your jurisdiction.

Whether it is physically possible or not usually depends on whether the programmer of the original chip set the "protection" lock bit or not. I don't know about that chip in particular, but it's very common.

Answer (score 1):

If the security fuse hasn't been blown, you can read the configuration of the chip out over JTAG with a suitable adaptor and access to the right pins.  You can then programme that into another chip of the same sort (check the speed-grades are the same) using the same interface.

If the fuse *is* blown, I'm not sure the JTAG interface can be used for anything much.

[This monster search](http://xgoogle.xilinx.com/search?q=xc9500+security&btnG=New+Search&getfields=%2a&numgm=5&filter=0&proxystylesheet=support&client=support&submit2=Search&output=xml_no_dtd&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&num=1000&getfields=%2a&show_dynamic_navigation=1&requiredfields=-status%3Aarchive&lang2search=&entqrm=0&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&site=Answers_Docs_Forums) on Xilinx's site might point you to some useful info...

Comment: If the fuse is blown, is there anyway to confirm that the chip is functional?  Will JTAG allow me to check if the chip is operating correctly? I am pretty sure the fuse is going to be blown. Security was a big thing with these arcade games.